# print the current time for every 30 minutes in a file

Tags: tcl

I have tried this code to print the current time for every 30 minutes in a file and also if day changes print the next day time in the newfile and second day file name is incremental of first day file name.
**But mistake of this code is it's not printing next days 30minutes increment time in new file created for that day.**

```
set i 1
set c [open "$i.txt" w+]
set a [clock seconds]
set b [expr {$a+1800}]
set d [expr {$a+86400}]
while {$a > 0} {
    incr a
    if {$a == $b} {
        if { $a == $d} {
            incr i
            set e [open "$i.txt" w+]
            puts $e "The time is: [clock format $a -format %H:%M:%S]"
            set d [expr {$a+86400}]
        }
        puts $c "The time is: [clock format $a -format %H:%M:%S]"
        set b [expr {$a+1800}]
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it have anything to do with Perl or Python? Please remove those tags.

Comment: You'll find maintaining your code will be easier if you don't use 1-character variable names.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested the code, but I'm guessing it's because you are still using `puts $c ...` even after creating the new file, and by the way, you should close the previous file if you are done with it. Only addressing the issue you mentioned, it should be more like:

```
set i 1
set c [open "$i.txt" w+]
set a [clock seconds]
set b [expr {$a+1800}]
set d [expr {$a+86400}]
while {$a > 0} {
    incr a
    if {$a == $b} {
        if { $a == $d} {
            close $c     ;# close the previous file
            incr i
            set c [open "$i.txt" w+] ;# open it in the same channel
            set d [expr {$a+86400}]
        }
        puts $c "The time is: [clock format $a -format %H:%M:%S]"
        set b [expr {$a+1800}]
    }
}
```

Comment: as day changes next days all 30 minutes increment times i.e., condition {$a == $b} should be printed in that new file 2.txt

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the `after` command to pause for 30 minutes:

```
proc day {time} {
    clock format $time -format %e
}

proc write_time {} {
    global file_number prev_time

    set time [clock seconds]

    if {[day $time] != [day $prev_time]} {
        incr file_number
    }

    set fh [open "$file_number.txt" a]  ;# open for append
    puts $fh [clock format $time -format %T]
    close $fh

    # wait 30 minutes in milliseconds
    after 1800000 write_time
}

set file_number 1
set prev_time [clock seconds]

write_time
vwait forever
```